# Pandas: How to increment a new column based on increment and consecutive properties of 2 other columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm currently working on a bulk data pre-processing framework in pandas and since I'm relatively new to pandas, I can't seem to solve this problem:

**Given:** A dataset with 2 columns :`col_1`, `col_2`

**Required:** A new column `req_col` such that it's value is incremented if
a. the values in `col_1` are not consecutive
OR
b.the value of `col_2` is incremented
consecutively

**NOTE:**

1. `col_2` always starts from `1` and always increases in value and values are never missing (always consecutive), eg:1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,9.....
2. `col_1` always starts from `0` and always increases in value, but some 
   values can be missing (need not be consecutive), eg:0,1,2,2,3,6,6,6,10,10,10...

**EXPECTED ANSWER**:

```
col_1  col_2  req_col      #Changes in req_col explained below
 0        1        1
 0        1        1
 0        2        2       #because col_2 value has incremented
 1        2        2
 1        2        2
 3        2        3       #because '3' is not consectutive to '1' in col_1
 3        3        4       #because of increment in col_2
 5        3        5       #because '5' is not consecutive to '3' in col_1
 6        4        6       #because of increment in col_2 and so on...
 6        4        6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df['req_col'] = (df['col_1'].diff().gt(1) | # col_1 is not consecutive
                 df['col_2'].diff().ne(0)   # col_2 is has a jump
                ).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    5
8    6
9    6
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried a lot of different code combinations but none of them worked, your solution is by far the most elegant solution I've encountered so far!